# jqGrid cell title and value not populated after using formatter:'select'

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, formatter

I have 2 columns (along with others)- L1Cat and L2Cat with edittype : "select". On selection of L1Cat, L2Cat is populated dynamically from prefetched master list(l2OfL1) of L2Cat. Below is the code for colModel of the 2 said columns:

```
{ name: 'L1Cat', width: 160, editable: true,align : "right",sortable : false, formatter: 'select',
                edittype: 'select', editoptions: {
                    value: l1,
                    dataInit: function (elem) {
                        var v = $(elem).val();

                        var sc = l2OfL1[v];
                        var newOptions = '';
                        for(var l2Index in sc) {
                            if (sc.hasOwnProperty(l2Index)) {
                                var ob = sc[l2Index];
                                for(var ab in ob){
                                    newOptions = newOptions + ab + ":" + ob[ab] + ";";
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        newOptions = newOptions.substring(0,newOptions.length - 1);
                        grid.setColProp('L2Cat', { editoptions: { value: newOptions} });
                    },
                    dataEvents: [
                        {
                            type: 'change',
                            fn: function(e) {

                                var v = parseInt($(e.target).val(), 10);
                                var sc = l2OfL1[v];
                                var newOptions = '';
                                for(var l2Index in sc) {
                                    if (sc.hasOwnProperty(l2Index)) {
                                        var ob = sc[l2Index];
                                        for(var ab in ob){
                                            newOptions += '<option role="option" value="' +
                                            ab + '">' +
                                                      ob[ab] + '</option>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                    // inline editing
                                    var row = $(e.target).closest('tr.jqgrow');
                                    var rowId = row.attr('id');
                                    $("select#" + rowId + "_L2Cat", row[0]).html(newOptions);

                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
            , {
                name : "L2Cat",
                width : 200,
                align : "right",
                sortable : false,
                edittype : "select",

                editable : true
            }
```

If I use formatter "select" in L1Cat, the values in all the rows for L1Cat is not displayed when the main grid data is loaded for the first time. When I click on inline edit button, both drop downs are populated and on saving the row, l1Cat value is visible. If I remove formatter : "select" in L1Cat, L1cat value is visible but on clicking the inline edit button, the dropdowns are empty.

Please let me know how to display the L1Cat values as well as populate the dropdowns on inline editing.

Comment: This sounds like the problem might be quite difficult to visualise and/or it is not something readers would immediately recognise. I wonder, if you are still looking for an answer, whether a JS Fiddle might help show what you mean?